# Postgres index is ignored on large table

Tags: postgresql

I have a pretty simple query with a single join that takes >10 minutes to complete on Postgres 11.12:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(r.*) as active_jobs 
    FROM project_raw_data r 
        INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = r.processing_job_id 
    WHERE r.ind_requires_processing = True AND
          r.processing_error = False AND
          r.processing_job_id IS NOT NULL AND
          j.finished IS NULL AND
          j.started IS NOT NULL;
```

The `project_raw_data` table has ~50M rows and is ~500GB in size (there's some larger metadata in there, the columns involved in this query are all `boolean` or `timezone`), and the `jobs` table has ~1M rows.

I have the following index applied on the `project_raw_data` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_project_raw_data_processing_active ON  
    project_raw_data 
    USING btree (ind_requires_processing, processing_error, processing_job_id);
```

And this one on the `jobs` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_studio_jobs_active ON 
    jobs 
    USING btree (id) WHERE ((finished IS NULL) AND (started IS NOT NULL));
```

If I look in PgAnalyze the indexes should already be optimal for this query:

[image: SQL statement and index analysis in PgAnalyze]

So I'm a little bit out of depth on why this has to take 10 minutes and read 70GB (!) from disk (when looking at the analysis).

Here's the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```sql
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=9860168.44..9860168.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=690627.757..690628.919 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=9860168.23..9860168.44 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=690625.874..690628.908 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=9859168.23..9859168.24 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=690623.471..690623.475 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=97.43..9859165.28 rows=1180 width=1135) (actual time=690623.464..690623.467 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Hash Cond: (r.processing_job_id = j.id)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on project_raw_data r  (cost=0.00..9845488.13 rows=5173208 width=1139) (actual time=690623.462..690623.463 rows=0 loops=3)
                          Filter: (ind_requires_processing AND (NOT processing_error) AND (processing_job_id IS NOT NULL))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 16661364
                    ->  Hash  (cost=93.42..93.42 rows=321 width=4) (never executed)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_studio_jobs_active on jobs j  (cost=0.27..93.42 rows=321 width=4) (never executed)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 2.207 ms
Execution Time: 690629.645 ms
```

We see that the index on the `project_raw_data` table is completely skipped. But why?

Comment: Does using `count(*)` change anything? Or at least `count(r.ind_requires_processing)`. There is a huge difference between the expected number of rows and the actual number of rows for that step. Try `analyze project_raw_data ;` or `vacuum analyze project_raw_data ;` to update the statistics

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow, actually running `analyze` on the table locally makes it use the index... Will run it on our production db now and see if that makes a difference. We have autovacuum enabled on the db, so didn't expect this to be needed. Hopefully this does resolve the issue.

Comment: Do your tables have Primary Keys? Do they have a FK relationship? Are these supported by constraints/indexes? These all should be defined *before* adding any additional indexes on non-key attributes.

Comment: @wildplasser, yes, tables have PK and FK relation exists between the two tables. They all have indices on them, and every column should be covered by existing indexes as shown in the PgAnalyze screenshot (can show all indexes on the tables if that helps).

Comment: Sorry, I don't read screenshots. DDL is easier to read. BTW: do you realise that the `r.processing_job_id IS NOT NULL` condition is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

@a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion in the comments to run `vacuum analyze` on the table did the trick. Query is now fully using the index, and is completing in 100ms. instead.